# How to bring up "send to" menu without going through the context menu

Tags: windows, shell, context-menu, productivity, organizer-software

Short story:
basically, I need a way to bring up the "send to" menu without going through the right-click context menu.. or a way to hide the main context menu itself after clicking on the "send to" entry

The long story of why I need that:
this might provide some context, and potentially be useful to someone else

so, through my work routine, I usually end up with tons of files in my downloads folder every couple of days or so, these files need to go to their respective folders eventually, throughout the years I came up with different ways to speed up the process of sending these files to their folders, I'm currently using a combination of Autohotkey and "Everything" search to hit a hotkey that ctl+x the files, bring up "Everything" where I can type the destination folder's name and hit another hotkey to paste the files into the folder.

this process is great and it served me very well for a long time, I can send any files into any folder anywhere on the computer in seconds, but of course, I have to type the names of the destination folders every time I want to move the files; I noticed that I have a dozen or so destination folders that I send files to the most, and I got the idea of adding shortcuts of these folders in the "send to" menu. now I can quickly hit a hotkey that brings up the context menu and opens the "send to" menu and I just have to click the destination folder and the files get sent there.. that saved me from having to type the names of the folders in "Everything" every time I need to move a file.. my only problem now is that I need to be real careful when moving the mouse not to hit any entries on the main context menu because it will make the "send to" menu disappear

this all might sound trivial to some, but when you're dealing with literally thousands of files sometimes, and repeating a certain process tens of times, then shaving off a few seconds here and extra steps there makes a huge difference. now getting the main context menu out of the way will smooth out the process a great deal and eliminate any potential hiccups during the process

any ideas are greatly appreciated, and thanks in advance

Comment: There's no way for that, you'd need to build your own menu with 3rd party app, e.g. AHK has some UI building capabilities.

Comment: I think that'd be the way to go, I just hoped there'd be a way to trigger the menu that I didn't know of, you know, to rule out the easy solution before going for a more complex one. Thanks man.